# Difference between 2 imports in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, import

I am an Angular beginner and I don't understand one point.  In following code, there are 2 imports for `BrowserModule`.  One is at the second line and another is in the `@ngmodule`.  So what is the difference between them and each roles?

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
**import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';**
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  **imports:      [ BrowserModule ],**
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I've edited your question - `AngularJS` refers to v1, `Angular` refers to all other versions.

Answer (score 5):

The first is the ES6 import, this has nothing to do with Angular specifically.  It just means "We need `BrowserModule` from the `@angular/platform-browser` package.

The second (passed into `NgModule`) *is* Angular specific.  This one tells Angular that the `AppModule` will be using the tools declared in `BrowserModule`.

Comment: Thanks.  But what about NgModule , why NgModule  didn't passed into @Ngmodule? I worked with Angularjs 1.0 but it differs from Angular2 very much

Comment: @WhiteSnow Please read this.https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/appmodule.html Dos always helps.